# How to query unique values with pull query in Kafka ksqldb

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Running the command below:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_STREAM WHERE speed != 0 GROUP BY name LIMIT 10;
```

results to an error:

`Pull queries don't support GROUP BY clauses.`

Is there a way to query 10 records with the `name` value being different and unique across all 10 records returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Also, you can include WINDOW for the specific duration.

```
  SELECT name, count(*) FROM MY_STREAM
  WHERE speed != 0
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING count(*) = 10
  EMIT CHANGES
  LIMIT 10;
```

### PULL QUERY

- Pulls the current value from the materialized table and terminate. The result of this statement will not be persisted in a Kafka topic and will only be printed out in the console.
- The WHERE clause must contain a single value of **ROWKEY** to retrieve and may optionally include bounds on WINDOWSTART if the materialized table is windowed.

Comment: Isn't the use of "EMIT CHANGES" only supported in push queries according to the documentation (https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/select-push-query/#emit)?